# Reinstalled the latest Anaconda3 and managed to launch Spyder. Now I an not able to import Panda and NymPy

Tags: pandas, numpy, import

The following error message comes up:   ModuleNotFoundError    Traceback (most recent call last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10096/148765715.py in  ----> 1 import Pandas as pd

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pandas'

A similar massage comes up upon importing NumPy.

Comment: python is case sensitive - try changing  `Pandas` to `pandas` (lower case)

Comment: I tried and the error does not come up! Many thanks! In found the commands with these typos in an otherwise excellent book by RAN TAO and 
CHRIS BROOKS RAN TAO Python Guide for Introductory Econometrics for Finance 4th edition. I should have known better..... Thanks very much!